# multiple simultaneous ajax requests broker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to coordinate simultaneous ajax calls and take action only when all of them are completed?

Is there a convenient javascript helper library that will coordinate multiple simultaneous ajax calls to a database  and  invoke a specified callback when ALL of the ajax data-fetches have returned their data?  I'd like to submit a dictionary of primed-and-ready-to-go ajax calls to this "coordinator" or "broker", along with my WhenAllCompleted callback function.

The use case is a common one:  before a database record can be bound to the UI, all of the dropdown lists for the foreign key data relationships have to be populated, so that the user sees meaningful values rather than the integer keys that are typically stored in the record.

I would rather not reinvent all the plumbing code to track the status of each ajax request if there's a robust standard library out there for doing it already.

EDIT:
Here's the pseudo-code that describes what I want to do :

```
           when ajax1fetch is finished
           and
           ajax2fetch is finished
           and 
           ajax3fetch is finished
           and SELECT1 is populated
           and SELECT2 is populated
           and SELECT3 is populated
           bindRecordToUI()
```

Before I restructured the code to use `$.when()`, I was getting the data in the .ajax() success callback, and populating the SELECT right there in that callback; when the  SELECT was populated, then I bind the record to the UI.

If we feed `$.when` a list of ajax calls, the done callback is invoked when the ajax requests are complete, which occurs *before* the SELECTs are populated (if the list of items for the SELECT is very long).

Somehow I need to include the population of the SELECT elements as additional when-conditions, and find a way to route the data returned by the ajax call to the populating functions, if the SELECT-populate functions are not going to be peformed in the .ajax success callback.

Comment: Sounds like you want [`jQuery.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), given that you're already using jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) in JS. Here is a nice framework [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). And the `allSettled()` function is, what you are looking for.

```
Q.allSettled([saveToDisk(), saveToCloud()]).spread(function (disk, cloud) {
    console.log("saved to disk:", disk.state === "fulfilled");
    console.log("saved to cloud:", cloud.state === "fulfilled");
}).done();
```

Code taken from the [API-reference](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference)

Comment: Why include another library when one already in use (jQuery) has this support out-of-box?

Comment: @ajp15243: Because Q is much better :-) Of course, it depends on how much functionality is required

Comment: @Bergi I'm certainly not blindly arguing for jQuery. However, Q would also separate out the futures/deferred/promise functionality so that if the code was ever migrated from jQuery to something else, that part wouldn't need to be touched. Honestly I'm liking this answer better than mine now :P.

Comment: Which would better handle the problem I encountered, where the ajax call is done but populating the UI SELECT with the data is not yet done.  I don't want to bind my record to the UI until all of the SELECTs have been populated, which occurs some time after the data have been fetched.

Comment: @Tim It sounds like your problem is a little more fundamental to asynchronous tasks, rather than library-dependent, but q could have some trick up its sleeve.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using jQuery, you can use the [`jQuery.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) method to wait for multiple [`Deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)s to finish.  Note that `jQuery.ajax()` (and its wrapper methods, like `jQuery.get()`) returns a `jqXHR` object that is a type of `Deferred`.

You'll get your `Deferred`s from your `$.ajax` or equivalent calls, and then pass those all to `$.when`.  You will get back a [`Promise`](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise), which is basically a read-only `Deferred`*. You can then attach completion/error handlers to this `Promise`, which will be resolved once all of your passed-in `Deferred`s are resolved, or is rejected if any one of your `Deferred`s is rejected.

```
var def1 = $.ajax(),
    def2 = $.ajax({ /* some params */});

var masterPromise = $.when(def1, def2);

masterPromise.done(function() {
    console.log('def1 and def2 are done!');
});
```

---

- A `Deferred` allows attaching various done and error handlers, as well as resolving and canceling and otherwise controlling the asynchronous action. A `Promise` only allows the attachment of handlers, and does not allow control over the asynchronous action. You can get a `Promise` from a jQuery `Deferred` with the `Deferred.promise()` method.

Comment: Thanks for a very good answer. I had already accepted Thomas's as the first in, but I'm voting you up.

Comment: @Tim Thanks. You can always change the accepted answer :). But I'll leave that up to you, as you'er the one that knows which answer is best for your situation.

Comment: Encountered a wrinkle :-)   What to do when one of the ajax calls returns many rows, and the `done` method of the `masterPromise' is invoked before the data rows are added to the dropdown?

Comment: @Tim I think technically that's another question... but one idea I just had is to do some deferred chaining. `d1` is your AJAX call that gets the rows. Don't pass it to `$.when`. Create another deferred yourself: `var d2 = $.Deferred();`. Pass `d2` to `$.when`. When `d1` is done, have a done handler populate the rows and then resolve `d2` (`d2.resolve()`). That way the rows will be populated before `d2` is resolved, and the `$.when` promise doesn't resolve until `d2` does, so you have a transitive wait on your row population. Make sense? It sounds kinda hacky to me, but should work.

Comment: OK. I'll pose it as another question.